# How to check if a string contains some specific char inside an execute shell in Jenkins?

Tags: regex, jenkins, sh

I have the following strings: deploy_tag and version_number .

deploy_tag can be "2.8.6.1" or "origin/master" and version_number can only be numeric separated by dots like "1.1.2.3".

I want to do something like that:

```
if [[ $deploy_tag == *["\/"+]* ]]; then deploy_tag=$version_number; fi
```

Meaning: If $deploy_tag contains "/" then set it's value with the value of $version_number.

This whole shell script is part of a shell execution within a Jenkins job.

The problem is that seems like something is wrong with my regex but I can't find what... can you?

I checked some other questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find the issue with my regex.

Edit #1:
Here's an example from Jenkins build log:

```
[social-portal] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1162745529550311655.sh
+ [[ origin/master =~ / ]]
/tmp/hudson1162745529550311655.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson1162745529550311655.sh: [[: not found
+ echo deploy: origin/master
deploy: origin/master
+ echo version: 2.7.4
version: 2.7.4
+ mkdir output
```

And that's the code which generates the problem (including debug echo's):

```
if [[ $DEPLOY_TAG =~ / ]]; then DEPLOY_TAG=$VERSION_NUMBER; fi
echo deploy: $DEPLOY_TAG
echo version: $VERSION_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is using `/bin/sh`, which you cannot assume is `bash`. Even if `/bin/sh` is a link to some version of `bash`, some `bash` features may not work properly. You need to use a POSIX-compatible construct.

```
case $deploy_tag in
  */* ) deploy_tag=$version_number ;;
esac
```